# Solve n choose k for large numbers using 64 bit ints with no overflow

Tags: java, math

I have this assignment:

> Write a program using 64-bit integers that displays the value of *n* choose *k* for given *n* and *k*. Your program should not access any multiple precision features such as `BigInteger` in Java.

How would I do this without causing overflow?

Comment: That is the full assignment specification (I know, very brief but this is what makes the paper difficult) I think the main premise of the task is to rearrange the maths to make it work and not overflow, but unfortunately I'm not that math savvy :(

Comment: Nope this is literally the whole thing : Write a program using 64-bit integers that displays the value of (nk) for given n and k.  Your program should not access any multiple precision features such as BigIntegerin Java.

Comment: The assignment is certainly well-defined if you adjust it to "Display the value of min(n choose k, Long.MAX_VALUE) if n and k are nonnegative 64-bit integers." It's certainly possible, and I can even point to an implementation that doesn't use BigInteger.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we interpret this as "display n choose k, assuming n and k are nonnegative longs and n choose k is known to fit in a long," this is certainly possible.  Since it's an assignment, I won't link directly to a solution, only mention that one is present in Guava's `LongMath` class.  I will attempt to sketch how it works, however.

The standard loop to calculate n choose k looks like, approximately,

```
if (k > n / 2) {
  k = n - k;
}
long result = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= k; n--, i++) {
  result *= n;
  result /= i;
}
return result;
```

Using this unaltered will certainly overflow for big enough values.  However, an important fact is that at each step of the `for` loop, the division is exact with no remainder.  You can deduce this by noticing that when you execute this loop for a given value of `i`, you have just computed `n` choose `i`.

So what you have to do is rewrite the body of this loop in a way that doesn't overflow, assuming the result doesn't itself overflow.

Let `d` be the greatest common divisor of `result` and `i`.  Let
`resultD = result / d` and `iD = i / d`, so that 
`result = resultD * d` and `i = iD * d`.  So we can rewrite the fraction `result * n / i` to `(resultD * d * n) / (iD * d)` to `(resultD * n) / iD`.  We know this fraction is an exact integer, and we know `resultD` and `iD` have no common divisor (we divided it all out), so `n / iD` must itself be an integer.  So we can rewrite this as `resultD * (n / iD)` and do it all in `long` math, no fractions, no doubles.

Since we made sure `k <= n / 2`, the value of `result` only ever increases in this for loop, not decreases.  Additionally, `n / iD` definitely fits in a `long`, since `n / iD <= n` and `n` fits in a `long`.  So `resultD * (n / iD)` will only ever overflow if the actual value of n choose k would overflow.

So what you want for your loop is

```
long result = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= k; n--, i++) {
  // calculate resultD and iD...somehow
  result = resultD * (n / iD);
  // do something appropriate in the case of overflow, e.g. throwing or
  // returning Long.MAX_VALUE
}
return result;
```